# YouTube resumes playing video on old quality even after I change the quality setting

Tags: youtube

My YouTube app recently stopped allowing me the ability to change the video resolution.

For example, when watching a HD 720p video, if I go into YouTube video quality settings, the menu shows a list with all quality settings (auto, 144p, ... 720p). But if I select a new resolution, the window closes and resumes back to the video, but the resolution doesn't change.

How can I change the video resolution?

- YouTube app version: 10.08.53
- Android version: 4.4.2
- Device : Acer A3-A10 10" tablet

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache/data of the Youtube app?

Comment: @GiantTree thanks, that seemed to be the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wait a few seconds, YouTube adapts the resolution so that you can watch the video earlier at a lower resolution but it changes to a higher one once enough of the video is buffered/preloaded.
I noticed, that it may take up to 30 seconds for some videos depending on your bandwidth, but it definitely works.

As [AndrewT.](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/44325/andrew-t) pointed out:

> Youtube uses [MPEG-DASH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Adaptive_Streaming_over_HTTP), where "the client automatically selects from the alternatives the next segment to download and play back based on current network conditions. The client selects the segment with the highest bit rate possible that can be downloaded in time for play back without causing stalls or re-buffering events in the playback. Thus, an MPEG-DASH client can seamlessly adapt to changing network conditions, and provide high quality play back with fewer stalls or re-buffering events."

Comment: For more information: [MPEG-DASH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Adaptive_Streaming_over_HTTP), which the tech YouTube uses. "*The client selects the segment with the highest bit rate possible that can be downloaded in time for play back without causing stalls or re-buffering events in the playback. Thus, an MPEG-DASH client can seamlessly adapt to changing network conditions, and provide high quality play back with fewer stalls or re-buffering events.*"

Comment: @AndrewT. thanks for that extra information. Should I add this to the answer?

Comment: It's up to you if you want to add the technical side (I usually do though, as reference to backup the answer) :)

Comment: This didn't work for me. Nothing happens when I change resolution, and going back to resolution screen after making the selection shows no effect.

Comment: @SMeznaric you mean when you change the resolution to 720p it doesn't switch to 720p? This could be caused by a number of issues (YouTube app showing bugs, ISP blocking traffic etc.)

Comment: I would imagine it might be a bug. Watching a playlist (all videos uploaded by the same guy in the same set of qualities), only showing this issue with a specific episode.

Comment: Tried clearing the cache. That seems to reset the resolution, but after trying to set it to 720 it actually drops it down to 280. Quite frustrating.